# Use of $ symbol instead of %

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, sql-like

I have started practising SQL and I think I need to brush up some topics.

This problem statement in hackerrank states that the query lists CITY names from STATION that do not end with vowels.

I tried using wildcard `'%[^aeiou]'`

```
SELECT Distinct City 
FROM Station 
Where City LIKE '%[^aeiou]'
Order By City;
```

> Compiler Message: Answer Wrong.

I know other methods to execute the program but what is wrong with this one. Also, I am wondering how REGEXP `'[^aiueo]$'` is working but `Like '%[^aeiou]` or `Not Like '%[aeiou]'` is not executable?

Comment: Because LIKE and regex are pretty much incompatible. They're different tools for different (but similar) jobs. Combining them doesn't make any sense, really. LIKE does a simple match on specific text e.g. `LIKE '%ball'` would return all fields containing (exactly) "ball" at the end, e.g. football, baseball, netball etc. But saying "like this regex" (as per your code) makes no sense - the regex is already a different, more sophisticated way of filtering the data. It already has a different way to specify whether you are looking for matches at the end of the field, or the beginning, or anywhere.

Comment: It both doesn't make any sense to combine LIKE with a regex, and you also don't need to, because a regex can do everything that LIKE can do, and a lot more besides. use LIKE when you need a very simple "is this string inside this field" match, and use regex when you need something more complicated (like the above example where you are looking for fields which might end with one of several different characters)

Comment: `LIKE` only supports wildcards, `REGEXP` has full regular expression support.

Comment: @swapnilindahood If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. Otherwise write how you solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` only supports wildcards and you use for very simple match.

`REGEXP` or `RLIKE` has full regular expression support.

> A regular expression is a powerful way of specifying a pattern for a
>   complex search. This section discusses the functions and operators
>   available for regular expression matching and illustrates, with
>   examples, some of the special characters and constructs that can be
>   used for regular expression operations.

See the manual on [LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) and on [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)

If you must use `LIKE` try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT City 
FROM Station 
WHERE City NOT LIKE '%a'
OR City NOT LIKE '%e'
OR City NOT LIKE '%i'
OR City NOT LIKE '%o'
OR City NOT LIKE '%u';
```

If you want a faster query use [RIGHT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) ([Gordon Linoff answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56630441/10662353)) or `REGEXP`

Comment: Can we solve this problem statement using LIKE and wildcards? If No, what is the possible reason?

Comment: @swapnilindahood you can't solve the "content which does not end with vowels" problem using LIKE, no . That's because, as I explained above, LIKE just does a simple search for a fixed piece of text. It cannot search for any of a set of possible alternatives, which is what that regex is doing. You could do that using a series of LIKE clauses separated with OR, but it's probably less efficient to run (and certainly less efficient to write) than a regex

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not support SQL Server extensions for `LIKE`.  Use regular expressions instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT City 
FROM Station 
WHERE City REGEXP '[^aeiou]$'
ORDER BY City;
```

Note that you have to anchor the regular expression to the end of the string.  `LIKE` patterns automatically match the entire string; `REGEXP` patterns can match anywhere in the string, unless anchored to the beginning or end.

Or, eschew regular expressions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT City 
FROM Station 
WHERE RIGHT(City, 1) NOT IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
ORDER BY City;
```